# How to determine if a time series is significantly greater than, less than, or equal to another time series?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two stationary time series (tested with ADF and PP) and I would like to determine if one of these time series is significantly greater than, less than, or equal to the other time series over the sample period. Both time series contain an equal number of observations made at hour intervals.

I can report on the percentage of observations from series 1 that are greater, lower, or equal to series 2, but I'm not sure if that would be a statistically "sound" way of approaching the problem.

I'm not sure if it matters, but there is substantial auto-correlation in both series.

Comment: Maybe try timeseries bootstrapping?

Comment: Some details would be useful--indeed, probably necessary--for developing good answers.  The reason is that there are many potential solutions, ranging from modeling the differences (or ratios, or more generally differences of monotonic transformations) of the values all the way to modeling the two series as a bivariate time series (to capture more nuanced information about the autocorrelation).  Note, too, that you haven't assessed whether the bivariate series is stationary: can that be assumed?